# problem writing HTMLUnit script for YUI form submit

Tags: forms, button, yui, jenkins, htmlunit

I want to write a simple HTMLUnit test script for Jenkins (former Hudson). INFO: Jenkins uses the YUI Javascript library. The YUI library replaces the form submit with a custom button. The script just creates a new job in Jenkins.

start Jenkins:
java -jar jenkins.war

Current versions of HTMLUnit do not support form.submit any more and require you to use button.click() for form submitting. Unfortunately this does not work for Jenkins (the sample below does not advance the page and create the job but stays on the new job page)

I tried for some hours now to find a solution or workaround but so far I could not get the form submitted. Hopefully somebody has found a solution and let me know.

Here is my sample code:

```
package example;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlButton;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;

public class jenkins3 {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
        // create a new job in jenkins
        // home
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
        try {
            final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:8080");
            //assertEquals("Dashboard [Jenkins]", page1.getTitleText());

            // new job
            final HtmlAnchor new_job = page1.getAnchorByText("New Job");
            final HtmlPage page2 = new_job.click();

            // job name
            HtmlTextInput name_field = (HtmlTextInput) page2.getElementById("name");
            name_field.type("new job by htmlunit");

            // radio button
            final HtmlInput radio_freestyle = (HtmlInput) page2.getByXPath("//input[@value='hudson.model.FreeStyleProject']").get(0);
            radio_freestyle.click();
            Thread.sleep(10000);

            // OK button (submit form)
            final HtmlForm form = page2.getFormByName("createItem");
            //final HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getByXPath("//button").get(0);
            final HtmlButton button = (HtmlButton) form.getByXPath("//button").get(0);

            final HtmlPage page3 = button.click(); // !!!!! Form submit does not workstacko
            //assertEquals("Dashboard [Jenkins]", page3.getTitleText());
        }

        catch( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println( "General exception thrown:" + e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you submit the form when you look at the page in a browser?  HtmlUnit typically tries to replicate human interaction with a page, not DOM-level things you can't do via the browser.

Comment: As I stated above Jenkins uses the YUI Javascript library. The YUI library replaces the form submit with a custom button. This button triggers the form submit action and does some magic behind the scenes like mangling all the input fields into one hidden field prior to form submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this may be completely out of the question in your senerio: i would suggest giving up on HTMLUnit. I've had bug after bug, mainly because of the pages I've been automating tests for aren't always 100% valid html (3rd party piggybacked requests). I finally went looking elsewhere and found PhantomJS (js bindings to the WebKit engine) much better suited.
For me the advantages were evident:
- no need for another app server
- much simpler and faster to script JS than Java
- a "real"-world engine is more realistic than a buggy emulator one
Thats my advice,
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

HTMLUnit doesn't include support for testing javascript actions.  You might not want to switch your testing framework at this point, but I would recommend using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for this kind of testing.  It runs a mock browser and executes javascript, making it possible to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this little trick to work. Navigate to the Jenkins login page using HtmlUnit. Add a Submit button to the login form. Set appropriate attributes to Submit element, including an "onclick" value. Click on this new button and viola! You're logged in.

Note, if you're not concerned about security, you can also do this:

```
webClient.getPage("https://yourdomain:8443/jenkins/j_acegi_security_check?j_username=yourUsername&j_password=yourPassword");
```

See below for first method.

Enjoy,
Nick.

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class JenkinsLogin {

  final String urlValue = "https://<yourdomain>:8443/jenkins";
  private final String userName = "yourUsername";
  private final String password = "yourPassword";
  protected static final BrowserVersion BROWSER_VERSION_FIREFOX = new BrowserVersion(
          "Netscape", "5.0 (Windows)",
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0",
          (float) 1.2);
  private final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BROWSER_VERSION_FIREFOX);

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final JenkinsLogin jenkinsLogin = new JenkinsLogin();
    jenkinsLogin.login();
  }

  private void login() throws Exception {

    this.webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

    HtmlPage page = this.webClient.getPage(this.urlValue + "/login");

    final HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("login");
    form.getInputByName("j_username").setValueAttribute(this.userName);
    form.getInputByName("j_password").setValueAttribute(this.password);

    final HtmlElement createdElement = page.createElement("input");
    createdElement.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    createdElement.setAttribute("name", "submitIt");
    createdElement.setAttribute("onclick", "login.submit();");
    form.appendChild(createdElement);

    final HtmlElement submitButton = form.getInputByName("submitIt");
    page = submitButton.click();

    final HtmlElement loginField = page.getFirstByXPath("id('login-field')");
    if (loginField == null || !loginField.getTextContent().contains(this.userName))
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to log on to Jenkins. ");
    System.out.println("Logged in! ");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does replacing

```
final HtmlButton button = (HtmlButton) form.getByXPath("//button").get(0);
final HtmlPage page3 = button.click()
```

with

```
form.submit((HtmlButton)last(form.getHtmlElementsByTagName("button")));
```

work?

Comment: No it does not. As I stated in the original question the current version of HTMLUnit does not support form submit.

Comment: Have you considered using YUI Connection manager?
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/connection/#forms

Comment: I have the impression that it is not clear to you that I am testing Jenkins as it is and I am not going to change it. So it is a testing related question and not development.